# Angular jquery plugin wrapper against data from ajax call

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to write a basic jquery plugin wrapper directive but the problem I keep facing is that angular has not rendered the bound data when the plugin is called within the link function.

from html:

```
<my-syntax ng-bind="snippet.code"></my-syntax>
```

the directive:

```
angular.module('myDemo').directive('mySyntax', function($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<pre><code></code></pre>',
    link: function(scope, element) {
        // this timeout seems brittle, need better solution
        $timeout(function() {
            element.each(function(i, e) { hljs.highlightBlock(e) });
        }, 50);
    }
});
```

the highlightjs plugin relies on the content of the element, but since that is coming from 
my "snippet.code" scope binding, and that value is coming from an ajax call, the jquery plugin is executing against something that hasn't rendered yet. I have "solved" this by wrapping the jqueryPlugin call in a $timeout with 50ms but that seems very brittle. I have also tried using isolated scope and wrapping the jqueryPlugin call in a watch on the scope variable but in this case nothing renders at all (and no js errors are occurring). I would think this is a very common type of directive but I have yet to find a solution to this problem.

Attempt:

```
<my-syntax code="snippet.code"></my-syntax>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('myDemo').directive('mySyntax', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<pre><code>{{code}}</code></pre>',
        scope: {
            code: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.$watch('code', function() {
                element.each(function(i, e) { hljs.highlightBlock(e) });
            }, 50);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second attempt is almost correct.

The problem is that the first time the listener function for the watcher is executed both the new and old value will be undefined. This means the `highlightBlock` function will run twice, which it cannot handle:

> You can use highlightBlock to highlight blocks dynamically inserted
>   into the page. Just make sure you don't do it twice for already
>   highlighted blocks.

Example:

```
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  template: '<pre><code>{{code}}</code></pre>',
  scope: {
    code: '='
  },
  link: function(scope, element) {

    var watchExpression = function() {
      return scope.code;
    };

    var listener = function(newValue, oldValue) {

      if (newValue === oldValue) return;

      element.each(function(i, e) {
        hljs.highlightBlock(e)
      });

      unregister();
    };

    var unregister = scope.$watch(watchExpression, listener);
  }
}
```

Since it cannot be run twice, I'm letting the `listener` function unregister the watcher when it's done.

*Also, the third parameter in `$watch` is a boolean that sets if to deep watch or not. In your example you are passing `50`, but I suspect it's a copy and paste error from the `$timeout` attempt.*

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/6j0BMxjNX88GchXCIlJq?p=preview